# Rebase numeric columns in a CSV file

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a data file as follows:

```
G70,ge,33,61,ge,CD,33,40,CD,in,40,50,INt,CD,50,61,CD
G83,ge,53,98,ge,CD,53,60,CD,in,60,68,INt,CD,68,75,CD,75,98,hg
```

In each line, I need to rebase all the numeric columns relative to one less than the value in the third column.

The final result should be as follows. In reality I have a much bigger file and the number of columns is different

```
G70,ge,1,29,ge,CD,1,8,CD,in,8,18,INt,CD,18,29,CD
G83,ge,1,46,ge,CD,1,8,CD,in,8,15,INt,CD,15,23,CD,23,46,hg
```

I have tried this awk code, but it doesn't work for me

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=4){array[i] = i+1;} {for(i in array) printf $i-$3+1""$array[i]-$3+1""FS;print ""}'
```

Please help me to get this working. Or alternatively a Perl or Python solution is fine.

Comment: Could you edit your post to show your desired output for the data?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43257539/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: Input - `G70,ge,33,61,ge,CD,33,40,CD,in,-----40,50------,INt,CD,------50,61------,CD`
Output - `G70,ge,1,29,ge,CD,1,8,CD,in,------8,18------,INt,CD,------18,29------,CD`
As per your question there is not matched on your output. Please check the post.

Comment: Yes, I have  update my question and add the resulted I want to get.

Comment: Your math doesn't seem to add up.  Please verify second row.

Comment: Now that you have a Perl answer and a Python answer, why have you removed the Perl and Python tags and the sentence saying that solutions using them were acceptable?

Comment: @ghoti: I don't understand how you can see this as a request for a recommendation for a tool. The OP says that they are trying to use an awk array to solve the problem and they show their non-working awk code, asking for help to fix it. This question is off topic in no way, and I think you should retract your votes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Python.

```
import csv

lists = list()
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        v = int(row[2]) - 1
        lists.append([int(item) - v if item.isdigit() else item for item in row])


print(lists)
"""
[['G70', 'ge', 1, 29, 'ge', 'CD', 1, 8, 'CD', 'in', 8, 18, 'INt', 'CD', 18, 29, 'CD'], 
['G83', 'ge', 1, 46, 'ge', 'CD', 1, 8, 'CD', 'in', 8, 16, 'INt', 'CD', 16, 23, 'CD', 23, 46, 'hg']]
"""
```

Comment: @zhongpingxu, it covers the case you mentioned. Be aware of `item.isdigit()`.

Comment: I have a mistake. The same thread with awk script as Karafa's answer,  used ``item.isdigit()``to find the digital columns.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a Perl tag on this question and a specific sentence saying that Perl or Python solutions were also acceptable. I don't know why that has been removed

You may do this with Perl as follows

```
perl -pe '$b = (split /,/, $_, 4)[2]-1; s/\b(\d+)\b/$1-$b/eg;' myfile
```

Note that this assumes that none of the fields that need to be left unchanged contain decimal digits

#### output

```
G70,ge,1,29,ge,CD,1,8,CD,in,8,18,INt,CD,18,29,CD
G83,ge,1,46,ge,CD,1,8,CD,in,8,16,INt,CD,16,23,CD,23,46,hg
```

Comment: For someone voted to close this question because he think  I need is a tool, rather than a request for assistance with my own code. So, I selected to  remove. Nice, your perl onelines is powerful.

Comment: @zhongpingxu: **ghoti** was wrong in their assessment of your question. It is on topic but very unclear until you added the desired output. Don't be bullied!